# How do I solve this delta cycle clock delay issue

Tags: vhdl, simulation

I have the following simplified example of my code, where the `DeltasTest` entity can be simulated to show the issue. The clock in the real design is inverted or not based on a generic, and feeds several other entities below this one.

The problem is that the simple edge detector does not work (`data_out` is just a glitch) in behavioral simulation, due to the delta cycle delay introduced on the clock by the inversion stage. Is there a standard or otherwise elegant way to solve this?

So far my best solution is to assign the `data_in` signal to another signal, to give it the same delta cycle delay as `clk`. I thought of using a function to invert the clock as necessary based on the generic as a second parameter to the function, but the clock is used in many places and this did not seem very elegant, and I was note sure it would even solve the problem. Clutching at straws, I also tried making the clock inversion assignment a `transport` assignment, but, as expected, this made no difference.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Deltas is
    Generic (
        CLK_INVERT : boolean := false
    );
    Port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        data_in : in std_logic
    );
end Deltas;

architecture Behavioral of Deltas is

    -- Signals
    signal data_reg : std_logic := '0';
    signal clk_inverted : std_logic := '0';
    signal data_out : std_logic := '0';

begin

    ClkInvert : if (CLK_INVERT) generate
        clk_inverted <= not clk;
    else generate
        clk_inverted <= clk;
    end generate;

    process (clk_inverted)  
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk_inverted)) then
            data_reg <= data_in;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (data_reg, data_in) 
    begin
        if (data_reg /= data_in) then
            data_out <= '1';
        else
            data_out <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Other entities use `clk_inverted`. Commented out so that this example compiles
    --LowerEntity : entity work.Counter
    --port map (
    --  clk => clk_inverted
    --);

end Behavioral;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity DeltasTest is
end DeltasTest;

architecture Behavioral of DeltasTest is

    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal data_in : std_logic := '0';

begin

    clk <= not clk after 10 ns;

    process (clk)
        variable count : integer := 0;
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            count := count + 1;
            if (count = 4) then
                count := 0;
                data_in <= not data_in;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    uut : entity work.Deltas
    Port map (
        clk => clk,
        data_in => data_in
    );

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Two issues: 1) Why ain't `falling_edge()` used in `Deltas`, instead of generating a `clk_inverted` with delta delay and then use `rising_edge()` on this ?  2) Why ain't stimuli on `data_in` generated based on `clk`, as it would in an actual design, instead of just based on time ?  Changing this would make the edge detector work.  If an inverted clock is needed, then make this at toplevel besides clk, and distribute through the hierarchy.

Comment: @MortenZilmer Thanks for the comments. 1) I'm not using `falling_edge()` because the clock polarity depends on a generic. 2) The data signal actually is generated by `clk`, but this ultimately does not make any difference as my example was not exactly the same as my real code. I will update the example to include your change.

Comment: You might find a wider audience over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your "solution" of an additional delta cycle on `data_in` is probably the cleanest simple solution.

Semantically, the assignment to `clk_inverted` could translate into hardware as an inverter in the clock signal, thus the delta cycle delay in simulation represents a (possibly(*) real) race condition introduced in the real hardware.

Thus the simulation behaviour is not merely an annoyance but a useful property, warning you of a potential deviation from good synchronous design practice that must be attended to.

(*) Only "possibly real" because, depending on the technology, synthesis may "push" the inversion into the downstream FF by detecting the opposite edge instead - automatically converting your design per Morten's comment.

It becomes more of a problem when the additional delta cycle is buried in somebody else's IP, perhaps a model of an external component such as memory. The IP is then no longer under your control, and a board level simulation may read or write data in the wrong clock cycle.

Here, my answer is to add approximate I/O delays, either as inertial delays in the FPGA's I/O assignments (from the FPGA datasheet or synthesis report), or as transport delays on the PCB. This ensures my simulations approximate teh behaviour of the board - not perfectly, but closely enough to allow me to design the internal logic following normal synchronous practice.

---

A cleaner solution would be to generate two different clocked processes based on the generic. This eliminates the pesky delta-cycle altogether.

FINALLY! a use for the 2-process form of SM, where keeping the clocked processes as simple as possible has a benefit ...

not so fast...

The behaviour you want to refactor is clock edge detection, which is already refactored into a simple function from the obsolete and complex (level and event) expression.

Why not refactor the clock edge detection further, for example...

```
function clock_edge(signal clk : in std_logic) return boolean is
begin
   if CLK_INVERT then
      return falling_edge(clk);
   else 
      return rising_edge(clk);
   end if;
end clock_edge;
...

process (my_clock) is
begin
   if clock_edge(my_clk) then ...
```

I have not tested this to see if synthesis tools can implement this as desired. Some probably will, some may not (if they simply special-cased the system-provided functions instead of doing the job properly)

In a hierarchical design, this function would be in a package, used by any entities that needed it. This poses problems of the visibility of the generic : one suggestion would be to use a constant in the package instead, another would be to pass the generic as a second parameter to the function. The right approach probably depends on restrictions imposed by the synthesis tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The data signal involved is actually created inside the FPGA in the same way shown in my updated test bench above in this particular design, but the entity in question could be used in a scenario where both signals are external inputs. Interesting point that this could be a real-world problem if an actual inverter was inserted.

Comment: Another solution would be to generate two different clocked processes based on the generic. FINALLY! a use for the 2-process form of SM, where keeping the clocked processes as simple as possible has a benefit!

Comment: Thanks for the additional ideas, I hadn't thought to have the clock edge function as a 'local' function, which would then not need to be passed the boolean every time, making this much cleaner that it would have been if done the way I was thinking. The main issue though with using a function in this case is that this entity has other entities below it which also use the inverted (or not) clock.

Comment: @scary_jeff You may add this restriction to the question.

Comment: @MartinZabel which 'this' are we referring to? I already have `The clock in the real design [...] feeds several other entities below this one`

Comment: @scary_jeff Sorry, missed it. You may instead extend your example code to reflect this (if you like).

Answer (score 1):

How about using the older style of clock and replacing CLK_INVERT with CLK_POLARITY.   Haven't done it myself, but I am pretty sure I have seen it somewhere.

```
entity Deltas is
    Generic (
        CLK_POLARITY : std_logic := '1'
    );
    Port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        data_in : in std_logic
    );
end Deltas;
architecture Behavioral of Deltas is
    signal data_reg : std_logic;
    signal data_out : std_logic;

begin

    process (clk)  
    begin
        if clk = CLK_POLARITY and clk'event then
            data_reg <= data_in;
        end if;
    end process;
```

This raises a bigger issue, how does one write IP that may for different designs need different clock polarity (as done here), different reset polarity, and different reset styles (asynchronous reset vs synchronous reset).  I think we need a package of procedures that implements flip-flops.  In addition to purpose built ones DFF with asynchronous reset, I think we could also have things like DFFR (DFF with reset) whose implementation is determined by the package body used.

```
-- In package body asynchronous resets
procedure DFFR (
  signal Clk   : std_logic ; 
  signal Reset : std_logic ; 
  signal DataIn : std_logic ;
  signal DataOut : std_logic ;
  constant ResetValue : std_logic 
) is
begin
  if Reset = RESET_POLARITY then 
    DataOut <= ResetValue ; 
  elsif Clk = CLOCK_POLARITY and Clk'event then 
    DataOut <= DataIn ; 
  end if ;
end procedure DFFR ; 

-- In package body synchronous resets
procedure DFFR (
  signal Clk   : std_logic ; 
  signal Reset : std_logic ; 
  signal DataIn : std_logic ;
  signal DataOut : std_logic ;
  constant ResetValue : std_logic 
) is
begin
  if Clk = CLOCK_POLARITY and Clk'event then 
    if Reset = RESET_POLARITY then 
      DataOut <= ResetValue ; 
    else
      DataOut <= DataIn ; 
    end if ;
  end if ; 
end procedure DFFR ; 

-- In package body power on reset by initialization
procedure DFFR (
  signal Clk   : std_logic ; 
  signal Reset : std_logic ; 
  signal DataIn : std_logic ;
  signal DataOut : std_logic ;
  constant ResetValue : std_logic 
) is
begin
  if Clk = CLOCK_POLARITY and Clk'event then 
    DataOut <= DataIn ; 
  end if ;
end procedure DFFR ;
```

Designs that make different decisions for different clock domains would need a separate library for each clock domain.

The upcoming IEEE 1076-2018 is doing a pilot for IEEE open source to open source the current VHDL packages.  Maybe we can get this in the next revision - however, currently I have more ideas than I have time, so we need more participants.

Comment: Wow, open source VHDL packages?! Hopefully we'll not get the proliferation as happened with the Linux kernel. Needs some proper review mechanism. Else VHDL tool vendors will only support the new standard very selectively (even worse then they're supporting VHDL-2008 now)

Comment: By the way, maybe, regarding the second code you don't need two packages. Just add a `SYNCHR_RESET` boolean generic, and use `if not SYNCHR_RESET and reset=RESET_POLARITY then [...] elsif clk=CLOCK_POLARITY and clk'event then if SYNCHR_RESET and reset=RESET_POLARITY then [...etc.]`. I think synthesis tools will accept this.

Comment: @JHBonarius  The importance of open source is distribution and in particular distribution with open source tools like GHDL.   Going further, WRT vendors, I only expect them to pay attention to the version released from the IEEE Open Source Group.   Processes still TBD, but I hope it mixes some of the good of both the IEEE and the open source approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a case of metastability occurring. you input data, if it is coming from the outside world might not be synchronized.

Clock data_in through two cascaded registers and make the comparison between to two register instead of comparing data_reg against the input signal.

I am pretty sure i have made this mistake before