# VHDL No Delta Delay Input to Output Assignment

Tags: vhdl

I've got a situation like the following:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164;

entity clkin_to_clkout is
port (
  clk_in : in std_logic;
  clk_out : out std_logic);
end entity clkin_to_clkout;

architecture arch of clkin_to_clkout is
begin

    clk_out <= clk_in;

end architecture arch;
```

The assignment of clk_in to clk_out isn't a problem for synthesis, but in a simulator it will induce a delta delay from clk_in to clk_out, thereby creating a clock crossing boundary. Is there any way to assign an entity output to an entity input without introducing a delta delay? Thanks.

Edit: Responses to some comments. First, I want this exact question answered, please. For clarification, I want the output port to behave exactly as if it were an alias of the input port. If the answer is, "In VHDL there is no possible way to make an output port an exact behavioral match of an input port", then that is the correct answer and I'll accept it as a limitation of the language. Second, if you don't see what the problem is, please instantiate the clkin_to_clkout entity in the following testbench and observe the difference between mr_sig_del_dly vs mr_sig_clk_dly when you simulate for a few clk1 cycles:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity delta_delay is
end entity delta_delay;

architecture arch of delta_delay is

  signal clk1: std_logic := '0';
  signal clk2 : std_logic;
  signal mr_sig : unsigned(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal mr_sig_del_dly : unsigned(7 downto 0);
  signal mr_sig_clk_dly : unsigned(7 downto 0);

  component clkin_to_clkout is
  port (
    clk_in : in std_logic;
    clk_out : out std_logic);
  end component clkin_to_clkout;

begin

  clk1 <= not clk1 after 10 ns;

  clk_inst : clkin_to_clkout
  port map (
    clk_in  => clk1,
    clk_out => clk2);

  mr_sig <= mr_sig + 1 when rising_edge(clk1);
  mr_sig_del_dly <= mr_sig when rising_edge(clk2);
  mr_sig_clk_dly <= mr_sig when rising_edge(clk1);

end architecture arch;
```

When you simulate, you will observe that mr_sig_clk_dly is delayed 1 clock cycle as expected because it is assigned on the same clock that mr_sig is on (clk1). mr_sig_del_dly is not delayed 1 clk1 cycle even though clk2 is just a passthrough of clk1 in the clkin_to_clkout module. This is because clk2 is a delta delayed version of clk1 because I used a signal assignment.
Again, thanks for all your responses.

Comment: Why is the delta delay a problem? A clock crossing boundary is not related to a delta delay.

Comment: Please see my comment to your answer.

Comment: I did. What's the use of this component anyhow? It seems your asking us to fix something that you think is a solution to your initial problem. Aka [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please tell us your initial problem.

Comment: This is pretty much the same question as the one that I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153003/how-do-i-solve-this-delta-cycle-clock-delay-issue

Comment: @scary_jeff  I added another answer (actually 2 different answers) to your older post

Comment: @MichaelGrover  For now, you have to create your design architecture understanding that this is an issue.   For VHDL-2018, see the "<=>" which does an association.   OTOH, you will have to wait some time for vendors to implement this in synthesis.

Comment: Delta delays don't *introduce* clock boundary crossing problems. However they may well *expose* such problems.

Comment: Any signal assignment creates a driver. Every driver introduces at least a delta delay when assigning values. Inputs and outputs are mappings, therefore they don't add delta delays. You can avoid delta delays, if your purpose is to "rename" a signal. Therefore you can use an *alias* declaration. In your case, an alias doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not know what a delta delay is.
A delta delay is an infinity small delay. Every assignment has (at least) a delta delay in simulation. That's just how VHDL works.

## edit:

After your comments, I see where you are coming from. The issue you are encountering is probably simulation only, as synthesis will simplify it. However, there is a electronic equivalent, being the multi-phase clocks. Consider you want a 2-phase clock, i.e. differential signal, where the second signal is the inverse of the first. If you would realize these clocks by just using one invertor, the second signal would have a phase offset. This is due to the latency of the invertor component. Thus, in clock generating logic (like PLL and DCM) the not-inverted signal is also delayed (using a variable latency buffer). I.e. ***all** clock signals need to be processed*, giving them the same (delta) delay.

The same solution can be applied in VHDL. Example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity clk_buffers is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        clk1 : out std_logic;
        clk2_n : out std_logic
        );
end entity;

architecture rtl of clk_buffers is begin
    clk1 <= clk;
    clk2_n <= not clk;
end architecture;

library ieee;

entity test_bench is end entity;
architecture behavioural of test_bench is
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    signal clk, clk1, clk2_n : std_logic := '1';
    signal base, child1, child2 : integer := 0;
begin
    clk <= not clk after 1 ns;

    clk_buffers_inst : entity work.clk_buffers
        port map(clk => clk, clk1 => clk1, clk2_n => clk2_n);
        
    base <= base+1 when rising_edge(clk1);
    child1 <= base when rising_edge(clk1);
    child2 <= base when falling_edge(clk2_n);
end architecture;
```

[image]

Comment: I know what a delta delay is, and this does create clock crossing issues in simulation because clk_in and clk_out are no longer the same clock anymore once the delta delay is introduced on clk_out. Consider if I have a higher entity that uses this entity and clock some signals on the clk_in clock in that higher entity. If I ever want to clock those same signals on clk_out, I have to instantiate a clock crossing mechanism (FIFO, extra flip-flop) to cross the boundary from clk_in to clk_out.

Comment: Have you actually tried to create the condition you described? Have you seen your perceived change in clock domains create an actual change in behaviour?

Comment: @DLnd no i haven't. But I'm not the one with the issue. Maybe you should comment the original question ;)

Comment: @michaelgrover I'm afraid that's because you're doing something wrong elsewhere. The code you show is perfectly normal and should not cause any issues.

Comment: @JHBonarius Sorry, that was intended as a reply to OPs comment rather than your answer.

Comment: Added some clarification to the question. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @MichaelGrover I expanded my answer after your edit. Maybe this is not what you want, but it's a way it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In VHDL-2008 or before there is no possible way to make an output port an exact behavioral match of an input port.
Reference Jim Lewis's comment to the original question.
Thanks, Jim and to all who opined.